# Extract matrix value according to vector elements and their positions, and returns a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have the following matrix `prob.matx`:

```r
prob.matx <- structure(c(0.182, 0.212, 0.364, 0.242, 0.242, 0.152, 0.394, 
                         0.212, 0.364, 0.091, 0.273, 0.273, 0.333, 0.242, 0.364, 0.061, 
                         0.273, 0.333, 0.212, 0.182, 0.303, 0.333, 0.182, 0.182), 
                       dim = c(4L, 6L), 
                       dimnames = list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 
                                       c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))
```

Which looks like this:

```r
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
A 0.182 0.242 0.364 0.333 0.273 0.303
C 0.212 0.152 0.091 0.242 0.333 0.333
G 0.364 0.394 0.273 0.364 0.212 0.182
T 0.242 0.212 0.273 0.061 0.182 0.182
```

And a vector `DNA`:

```r
DNA <- c("A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A")
```

I would like to extract the matrix values according to the element and position in the `DNA` vector, and return a vector. That is:

```r
c(prob.matx[DNA[1], 1], prob.matx[DNA[2], 2], prob.matx[DNA[3], 3], 
  prob.matx[DNA[4], 4], prob.matx[DNA[5], 5], prob.matx[DNA[6], 6])

[1] 0.182 0.152 0.091 0.242 0.333 0.303
```

This seems to be very simple, but I struggle to find a one-step function to do that  **WITHOUT** using `apply` or for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [@Darren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75766309/12158757) is good enough in terms of efficiency (unless you have extreme demand on speed). We can actually do a bit different to improve the speed based on @Darren's solution.

---

Let's think bigger and try harder

```
prob.matx <- matrix(rnorm(26 * 1000), 26, 10000, dimnames = list(LETTERS, paste0("V", 1:10000)))
DNA <- sample(LETTERS, 100000, replace = TRUE)

bench::mark(
  "Darren" = prob.matx[cbind(DNA, colnames(prob.matx))],
  "TIC" = prob.matx[cbind(match(DNA, row.names(prob.matx)), 1:ncol(prob.matx))]
)
```

and we will see

```
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
1 Darren       4.14ms  4.57ms    207.  6.69MB    19.3    86     8   415ms <dbl>
2 TIC           1.5ms     2ms    502.  3.09MB    18.9   213     8   424ms <dbl>
```

Answer (score 4):

We can index the `prob.matx` and extract the `diag` values.

```r
diag(prob.matx[DNA, ])

[1] 0.182 0.152 0.091 0.242 0.333 0.303
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, it is same as yours, there was no need for seq_along.

Comment: nice answer, concise! +1! The only drawback is that it would be memory expensive for long `DNA` vector.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a character matrix with one column per dimensions for indexing if the array has dimension names.

```r
prob.matx[cbind(DNA, colnames(prob.matx))]

# [1] 0.182 0.152 0.091 0.242 0.333 0.303
```

---

##### Benchmark

```r
prob.matx <- matrix(rnorm(26*100), 26, 100, dimnames = list(LETTERS, paste0('V', 1:100)))
DNA <- sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE)

bench::mark(
  "Darren" = prob.matx[cbind(DNA, colnames(prob.matx))],
  "benson23/zx8754" = diag(prob.matx[DNA, ])
)

# A tibble: 2 × 9
  expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 Darren             8.9µs    9.7µs    78756.    9.48KB     7.88  9999     1      127ms
2 benson23/zx8754   24.8µs   49.9µs    18694.   87.14KB    31.4   7737    13      414ms
```

Comment: Good answer, +1! It can be further improved using `prob.matx[cbind(match(DNA, row.names(prob.matx)), 1:ncol(prob.matx))]`, since indexing via names is not sufficient enough. You can try even bigger data